# logging module : StreamHandler does not seem to attach to logger

Tags: python, logging

I'm learning about Pythons logging module, and I cannot figure out why I cannot log DEBUG and INFO messages. Here's the code (python 2.7) :

```py
import logging

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    logger = logging.getLogger("test")
    c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logger.addHandler(c_handler)


    # test 
    logger.debug('This is a debug message')
    logger.info('This is an info message')
    logger.warning('This is a warning message')
    logger.error('This is an error message')
    logger.critical('This is a critical message')
```

this results in this output

```
This is a warning message
This is an error message
This is a critical message
```

i would expect this output

```
This is a debug message
This is an info message
This is a warning message
This is an error message
This is a critical message
```

it looks like the c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) is not working, and the logger uses its default setting. and by default, it will not log DEBUG and INFO logs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Handler handles the logs only. So it logger's logging level is higher, it ignores the lower levels, so handler never receives them.

Comment: So, basically, you need to do `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` as well, to get all log messages and pass them to handlers. Then, depending on your handlers and their config, you can get all info e.g. on stdout, only errors in one file, etc.

Answer (score 4):

[This diagram from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) (see below) helps explain how logging works. Notice the two diamonds near the top.
The "Logger flow" diamond checks "Logger enabled for level of call", while the "Handler flow" diamond checks "Handler enabled for level of LogRecord". This is alluding to the fact that 
both loggers and handlers have logging levels.

To log DEBUG level records, set the level of the *logger* to DEBUG (as well as having set the handler level to DEBUG):

```
logger = logging.getLogger("test")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

[image]

---

```
import logging

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    logger = logging.getLogger("test")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)    
    c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(c_handler)

    # test 
    logger.debug('This is a debug message')
    logger.info('This is an info message')
    logger.warning('This is a warning message')
    logger.error('This is an error message')
    logger.critical('This is a critical message')
```

prints

```
This is a debug message
This is an info message
This is a warning message
This is an error message
This is a critical message
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation

> The default level is WARNING, which means that only events of this
>   level and above will be tracked, unless the logging package is
>   configured to do otherwise.

You can add something like this after importing the logging package and it should work

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you all

using

```
 logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

dit the trick.

Incidently, I also tried

```
 logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

but that give this output :

```
 This is a debug message
DEBUG:test:This is a debug message
This is an info message
INFO:test:This is an info message
This is a warning message
WARNING:test:This is a warning message
This is an error message
ERROR:test:This is an error message
This is a critical message
CRITICAL:test:This is a critical message
```

Comment: `logging.basicConfig` is a convenience function for setting up handlers on the root logger. It is usually used as alternative to manually created loggers and handlers.